# Getting error in deploying code to parse cloud

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, mandrill

```
Parse.Cloud.define("email", function(request, response) {
 var Mandrill = require('mandrill');
 Mandrill.initialize('Dz74nd7RNATpV2Fj3tZ2yg');
  Mandrill.sendEmail({
  message: {
    text: request.params.text,
    subject: "otp!",
    from_email: "hatim@gmail.com",
    from_name: "hakim",
    to: [
        {
            email: request.params.email,
            name: "Some Name"
        }
    ]
},
async: true
 },{
success: function(httpResponse) {
    response.success("email sent");
},
   error: function(httpResponse) {

                 }
                 }
               );
  });
```

This gives an error while deploying as:

> "Unexpected token ILLEGAL in main.js: 4"

I am using Mac OS/X.
I'm trying to send an email for containing OTP using mandrill and parse cloud function.

Comment: Show us your main.js file. The error is in there and not in your swift-code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can then use the sendEmail function to fire off some emails. This function takes two parameters. The first is a hash with the Mailgun parameters you want to include in the request. The typical ones are from, to, subject and text, but you can find the full list on their documentation page. The second parameter to this function is an object with a success and an error field containing two callback functions.

```
Mailgun.sendEmail({
to: "email@example.com",
from: "Mailgun@CloudCode.com",
subject: "Hello from Cloud Code!",
text: "Using Parse and Mailgun is great!"
}, {
success: function(httpResponse) {
console.log(httpResponse);
response.success("Email sent!");
},
error: function(httpResponse) {
console.error(httpResponse);
response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");
}
});
```

For more help about Mailgun Cloud visit

https://www.parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Mailgun.html

Comment: but i want to use mandrill and find out the reason behing this error.. and thanks for replying